# Apache Beam - Read all files from directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I have a dataflow pipeline where i use the below AvroIO method to read a specific avro file with a known schema ..

However I would like to read all of the files inside a directory matching a file extension pattern recursively in the pipeline instead of reading a single file.. Need some help in this

```
pipeline.apply("Read from Avro",
 AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema).from("gcs://test/test.avro")
```

Comment: It appears that from() can specify wildcards.  Can you elaborate on the patterns for the AVRO files that you wish to consume?

Comment: If this is a missing feature in IO, another possible general idea is you could first read all filenames from the directory by ParDo, then output all files' name/path for parallel reading.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kolban suggested, "from()" accepts wildcards, as [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.java#L109) line suggests in the source code.